# How to show a calendar with input box by Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have one problem...

I want a calendar with input box.

If I click on any date it will show in that input box.

This calendar select multiple date.

All dates should be show in input box..

I'm attaching 2 Images

Thats what I'm getting

[image: Thats what I'm getting]

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

My code is as follows

HTML

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 multidate:true,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4 div-margin">
 <div class="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use input instead of div

Comment: I want to display calendar also.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code: i think this code helpful

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".DateField").datepicker({
multidate:true,
});
     
$(".table-condensed tbody").click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){ $('.abc').val($('.DateField[type=hidden]').val()); }, 1000)


});

     
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-4 div-margin">
 <div class="DateField" value='' type='text'><input type='hidden' class='DateField' value=''></div>
 
 <input type='text' class='abc' value='' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```